# Solaris 10, telnet after reboot gets disabled

Tags: solaris-10

I'm working with Solaris 10 and every time I `shutdown -y -g0 -i6` the telnet services gets disabled.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

To permanently enable telnet on Solaris 10:

```
 svcadm enable telnet
```

Answer (score 0):

what command do you use to enable it again?

anyway, could you paste here the output from `inetadm -l telnet`?